# sudo: command not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, gnu-screen

I am trying to execute `screen` as another user using `sudo`.

I'm using the command:

```
echo 'userpassword' | /usr/bin/sudo -u 'myuser' -S '/usr/bin/screen -ls'
```

Any help found on the internet says that the `sudo` clears the environment variables (like `PATH`). So I decided to use the full path to the applications but I'm still getting the **command not found** error.

Error:

```
sudo: /usr/bin/screen -ls: command not found
```

Sudo is installed on the system.
Screen is installed on the system.

For `sudo`, I have tried the `-E` and `-H` flag but it doesn't help.

I tried to set `PATH` variable using something like this:

```
... | /usr/bin/sudo -u 'myuser' -S 'env PATH=$PATH; /usr/bin/screen -ls'
```

Supposedly the `$PATH` was suppose to expand before the command executes but I was getting other errors...

Can someone provide a command that will let me execute commands as another user and explain what each part of the command does so I can understand it?

Thanks.

Comment: This questions is probably more proper on the StackExchange sites [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/) or [**ServerFault**](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Please update the question to show the exact (copy-and-pasted) error message. BTW, `sudo` doesn't completely reset `$PATH`; on my system it sets it to `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. Try [unix.se].

Comment: Okay, I'll go move it there.

Comment: `sudo` is trying to find the whole string `env PATH=$PATH....` as a single command instead of a command and parameters. `sudo` does reset `PATH`. In my test `sudo env` the result is `PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin` and my PATH is totally different than that. Try `sudo -u 'myuser' -S PATH=$PATH /usr/bin/screen -ls`. Note the absence of quotes in the command.

Answer (score 8):

Try,

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Probably you replaced the path variable while trying to set a new path variable.

Going forward, do 'echo $PATH' before adding a new path variable.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn's seem to be any need to encapsulate command in quotes, without them it even works.

`echo 'userpassword' | /usr/bin/sudo -u 'myuser' -S screen -ls`

Comment: Removing the quotes around the command worked. But why?
The command being passed in is an argument, and I used the escapeshellarg function in PHP to escape it.

Comment: @BradleyOdell - `escapeshellarg()` escapes all spaces between quotes.

Comment: @alvits I don't think so. It just adds single quotes around it.

Comment: @BradleyOdell - oops. I meant to say it escapes existing quotes. I should have just copied and pasted the text from here http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php